# How to Print i-net Crystel Clear Report ex:(report.rpt) in java without opening Print Dialog Bog

Tags: java, swing, struts2, crystal-reports, inet

> How to Print i-net Crystel Clear Report ex:(report.rpt) in java
> without opening Print Dialog Bog.

Can anybody give me some example in java using i-net crystel report.

example

Passing no of copies for page to print the report directly to printer.

Below Code which is running on server machine.while executing below code it printing the report on server default printer not client default printer machine.I wanted to print report on Client default printer machine which is set on client machine.

```
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setCopies(1);    
PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
RenderData data = new URLRenderData("url"); 
Progress progress = new PrinterJobProgress(null, printerJob, attributeSet, data);
progress.startProgress(); 
progress.waitUntilFinished();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try our "viewer programming guide" found here http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports/documentation/written-guides - this question is answered in full there. In short it's something like this:

```
   ￼￼￼￼ReportView reportView = viewer.createReportView(
             new URLRenderData("http://myreportserver:9000/?report=file:sample.rpt");
   reportView.print( 1, -1, false);
```

Comment: Thank u very much.I tried above code.and it's working for me.but here i got one problem that it's printing the report in Server machine not a client machine.My requirement is i wanted to printed report in client machine.please give some advice.

Comment: This code should work on a client which can access the Report Viewer, see the Viewer Programming Guide I linked to. If you need more detailed help, you can contact our support team at clearreports@inetsoftware.de